# unexplainable XML PARSE EXCEPTION on binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a databound control. As soon as I remove the binding from it, everything is fine. As soon as I try to bind it to a property, I get a XML parse Exception, who's description does not say anything useful.

```
<CheckBox Content="Include Missing" Checked="{Binding Path=IncludeMisssing}" />

public bool IncludeMisssing { get; set; }
```

It makes absolutely no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Name of the Property must be IsChecked

Comment: Just noticed it. Checked is the Event. IsChecked is the property Damn it. I did not notice it.